# Laplace of $\sinh t\sin t$

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to solve a question where we have to find the Laplace of the $f(t)$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2t}\sinh t\sin t }{t} dt.$$
Well I approach by converting the $f(t)$ to Laplace by assuming $s=2$, then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}\sinh t \sin t}{t}dt =L\left[\frac{\sinh t \sin t}{t}\right]$$
after this I easily convert the $t$ to intergral from $s$ to infinty but how to solve the Laplace of $\sinh t \sin t$, since the linearity does not apply here, I thought to use  $(e^{it} - e^{-it})/ (2i) =\sin t$ and the standard definition for $\sinh t$ to solve this question. Should I use this or is there any other way to solve the question?
A simple hint would be enough.

Comment: I tried to improve the presentation of your question but am not totally sure what you would like to say. You have for example both $dt$ and $dx$ but only one integral sign. What is $f(x)$? Could you please revise your question carefully?

Comment: @Gary sorry, it is just f(t), I corrected it, I just want to know is there any other way to find the laplace of sinh(t)sint without using the standard definitions.

Comment: By expressing the $\sinh$ via exponentials, your integral becomes $$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \frac{{\sin t}}{t}dt}  - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 3t} \frac{{\sin t}}{t}dt}.$$ Thus, you are looking for the value of the Laplace of $(\sin t)/t$ at the points $1$ and $3$. (See, e.g., https://planetmath.org/laplacetransformofsineintegral)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Gary's comment, famously $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan s$ whenever $\Re s>0$, so$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-st}\sinh t\sin t}{t}dt&=\frac12\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(s-1)t}\sin t}{t}dt-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(s+1)t}\sin t}{t}dt\right)\\&=\frac{\arctan(s+1)-\arctan(s-1)}{2}\end{align}$$when $\Re s>1$. For $s=2$, this is $\frac12\arctan 3-\frac{\pi}{8}$.